# Can we show the caret cursor as we drop files onto the CEdit control of a CDialogEx?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cdialog, cedit, oledragdrop

I have a `OnDropFiles` handler for a `CDialogEx`:

```
void CWeekendMeetingDlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
    __super::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);
    // ...

}
```

Example in action:

[image]

Is it possible to adjust it so that when the cursor is over the `CEdit` control is shows the  caret cursor to give more of an indication of where the data will be inserted?

Comment: I assume this is not possible. 